# How to extract an value from an external html page in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link example [this](http://denergod.store.aptoide.com/app/market/com.opera.mini.android/30/7144918/Opera%20Mini%20browser%20for%20Android)
Now I want to get the source of this page and extract the md5 hash value which is something like

```
<strong>MD5:</strong> 1b061e5530d2612135b8896482e68e3c</div>
<div>
```

I want to get the value **1b061e5530d2612135b8896482e68e3c** from it.

I have made an GET request and got the source code in an variable like:

```
$.get(link).done(function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

This seems to be working fine but I have no Idea how to proceed further kindly help me .
I have Searched but not got any helpful result.

Comment: You probably need server side (do you have server side for your app?) -- such things are blocked by the browsers/response headers: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'`

Comment: I just want to find an small part from the whole big html doc,Yes I have server side but I wanna do it using javascript(I am learning and wanna do this this way..)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) to get the text node containing the MD5 hash value:

```
$.get(link).done(function (data) {
    var md5Node = document.evaluate('//*[@id="app_info"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/text()', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    var md5String = md5Node.textContent;
    // ...
});
```

---

**A better XPath**

It would be better to find the MD5 text node based on its sibling's value. The XPath would look like

```
//*[text()="MD5:"]/../text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use good, old fashioned [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) (i.e., the second result of `/MD5:<\/strong> (.*?)<\/div>/g`).

```
var result = (/MD5:<\/strong> (.*?)<\/div>/g).exec([text])[1];
```

```js
var regex = /MD5:<\/strong> (.*?)<\/div>/g;
var output=document.getElementById("output");
var test="<strong>MD5:</strong> 1b061e5530d2612135b8896482e68e3c</div>";
var matches = regex.exec(test);
output.innerHTML="MD5 is "+matches[1];
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Does the div you're trying to get the value from have an ID? If so you could try something like this

```
$.get(link).done(function(data){ console.log($(data).find("#idofdiv").text()); });
```

Comment: Could you explain why this was downvoted? This seems to accomplish what the OP was trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use jQuery's `.load` function, like this:

```
$('div#container').load('external-page.html div#md5');
```

Comment: Why are you down voting? That is actually a fine way to get some data from an external page.